# replace multiple string values with different values in a column (python)

Tags: python, str-replace

Here is a sample dataset:

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | he wants some epples |
| 2 | she bought 2kgs of bakana |
| 3 | he got nothing |
| 4 | she took potato and tomat |

I wanted to replace it this way:

```
df['Description']= df['Description'].str.replace({'epples':'apples','bakana':'banana','tomat':'tomato'})
```

It returned error:

TypeError: replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'

What can I do to reach this result:

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | he wants some apples |
| 2 | she bought 2kgs of banana |
| 3 | he got nothing |
| 4 | she took potato and tomato |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4], 'Description':['he wants some epples', 'she bought 2kgs of bakana', 'he got nothing', 'she took potato and tomat']})
replacement = {
    "epples": "apples",
    "bakana": "banana",
    "tomat": "tomato"
}
print(df['Description'].replace(replacement, regex=True))
```

**Output :**

```
0          he wants some apples
1     she bought 2kgs of banana
2                he got nothing
3    she took potato and tomato
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, in `str.replace(something, toReplaceWith)`, you missed `toReplaceWith` so that it errors

Comment: It would be good to provide a correct version of the OP's code that will run without the error they encountered.